# Android:Receive Array of Objects and display in listView

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Hello to all android folks over there!!
I want to get list of objects from web service and want to display them in list view.Now i am able to fetch those values and collected them in arraylist.But i am facing problem to display them in list view.below is my code.

Using everyones suggestion ,i solved my problem.Thats the spirit of android buddies.I am pasting my answer in **UPDATED** block.Hope it will be helpful in future.

***UPDATED***

```
     public class TabFragment2 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    ListView FacultyList;
    View rootView;
    LinearLayout courseEmptyLayout;

    FacultyListAdapter facultyListAdapter;

    String feedbackresult,programtype,programname;
    Boolean FeedBackResponse;

    String FacultiesList[];
   public ArrayList<Faculty> facultylist = new ArrayList<Faculty>();

    SharedPreferences pref;
    FacultyListAdapter adapter;
    SessionSetting session;

    public TabFragment2(){
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("prefbook", getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
        programtype = pref.getString("programtype", "NOTHINGpref");

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_studenttab2, container, false);
        session = new SessionSetting(getActivity());

        new FacultySyncerBg().execute("");

        courseEmptyLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.feedback_empty_layout);

        FacultyList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.feedback_list);


        facultyListAdapter = new FacultyListAdapter(getActivity());
       FacultyList.setEmptyView(rootView.findViewById(R.id.feedback_list));
        FacultyList.setAdapter(facultyListAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }


    public class FacultyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
       private final Context context;

        public FacultyListAdapter(Context context) {

            this.context = context;

            if (!facultylist.isEmpty())
                courseEmptyLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                            ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder TabviewHolder;


            if (convertView == null) {

                TabviewHolder = new ViewHolder();


                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_feedback,
                        parent, false);

                TabviewHolder.FacultyName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.FacultyName);//facultyname

                TabviewHolder.rating = (RatingBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);//rating starts
                TabviewHolder.Submit = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

                // Save the holder with the view
                convertView.setTag(TabviewHolder);
            } else {


                TabviewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }


            final Faculty mFac = facultylist.get(position);//*****************************NOTICE
            TabviewHolder.FacultyName.setText(mFac.getEmployeename());
         //   TabviewHolder.ModuleName.setText(mFac.getSubject());


            TabviewHolder.rating.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                                            boolean fromUser) {

                    feedbackresult =String.valueOf(rating);

                }
            });


            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return facultylist.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {return facultylist.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView FacultyName;
        RatingBar rating;
        Button Submit;
    }

    private class FacultySyncerBg extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog= ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Faculty Feedback!","Fetching Faculty List", true);

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

            //CALLING WEBSERVICE
            Faculty(programtype);


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            /*if (FacultyList.getAdapter() != null) {
                if (FacultyList.getAdapter().getCount() == 0) {

                    FacultyList.setAdapter(facultyListAdapter);
                } else
                {
                    facultyListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            } else {
                FacultyList.setAdapter(facultyListAdapter);
            }


            progressDialog.dismiss();*/

            if (!facultylist.isEmpty()) {
              //  FacultyList.setVisibiltity(View.VISIBLE) ;
                courseEmptyLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);

                if (FacultyList.getAdapter() != null)
                {
                    if (FacultyList.getAdapter().getCount() == 0)
                    {
                        FacultyList.setAdapter(facultyListAdapter);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        facultyListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    FacultyList.setAdapter(facultyListAdapter);
                }
            }else
            {
                courseEmptyLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
               // FacultyList.setVisibiltity(View.GONE) ;

            }



            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }


    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser && isResumed()) {

            new FacultySyncerBg().execute("");
        }
    }//end*


    //**************************WEBSERVICE CODE***********************************

    public void Faculty(String programtype)

    {

        String URL ="http://detelearning.cloudapp.net/det_skill_webservice/service.php?wsdl";
        String METHOD_NAMEFACULTY = "getUserInfo";
        String NAMESPACEFAC="http://localhost", SOAPACTIONFAC="http://detelearning.cloudapp.net/det_skill_webservice/service.php/getUserInfo";


        String faculty[]=new String[4];//changeit

        String webprogramtype="flag";

        String programname="DESHPANDE SUSANDHI ELECTRICIAN FELLOWSHIP";
        // Create request
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACEFAC, METHOD_NAMEFACULTY);


        request.addProperty("fellowshipname", programname);
        // Create envelope
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        // Set output SOAP object
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        // Create HTTP call object
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {

            //my code Calling Soap Action
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAPACTIONFAC, envelope);

          //  ArrayList<Faculty> facultylist = new ArrayList<Faculty>();

            java.util.Vector<SoapObject> rs = (java.util.Vector<SoapObject>) envelope.getResponse();

            if (rs != null)
            {
                for (SoapObject cs : rs)
                {
                    Faculty rp = new Faculty();



                    rp.setEmployeename(cs.getProperty(0).toString());//program name
                    rp.setEmployeeid(cs.getProperty(1).toString());//employee name


                    facultylist.add(rp);
                }
            }


        }
        catch (Exception e) {


            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Why `ArrayList<Faculty> facultylist = new ArrayList<Faculty>();` line in `getView` method. use  same  `facultylist` object in which adding items in `Faculty`

Comment: yaeh i just added it for safer side.i will remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (lstView.getAdapter() != null) {
    if (lstView.getAdapter().getCount() == 0) {
        lstView.setAdapter(finalAdapter);
    } else {
        finalAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
} else {
    lstView.setAdapter(finalAdapter);
}
```

and `setVisibiltity(View.VISIBLE)`for listview

Put this code here

```
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
if (!facultylist.isEmpty()) {
 FacultyList.setVisibiltity(View.VISIBLE) ;
courseEmptyLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
    if (FacultyList.getAdapter() != null) {
                    if (FacultyList.getAdapter().getCount() == 0) {
                        FacultyList.setAdapter(facultyListAdapter);
                    } else {
                        facultyListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                } else {
                    FacultyList.setAdapter(facultyListAdapter);
                }
}else{
 courseEmptyLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
FacultyList.setVisibiltity(View.GONE) ;

}



    progressDialog.dismiss();

}
```

Comment: should i edit your suggestion in my `getView()` method?.I got confused can u explain me little!

Comment: I modified my answer, and commented where you need to modify your code.

Comment: Dkb,setAdapter and getAdapter showing error?what are they??

Comment: They are listview methods, call them using ListView object which is in your case ListView FacultyList, so use FacultyList.getadapter() & FacultyList.setadapter()

Comment: But still my listview is not displaying.Is ther ll be other way?? ;-(

Comment: remove    ArrayList<Faculty> facultylist = new ArrayList<Faculty>(); from your asyncTask method

Comment: `FacultyList.setVisibiltity(View.GONE) ;` this is not possible.it gives error

Comment: That was a typo mistake , i hope you know it's setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); & remove ArrayList<Faculty> facultylist = new ArrayList<Faculty>(); from your   public void Faculty(String programtype) method

Comment: Remove  ArrayList<Faculty> facultylist = new ArrayList<Faculty>(); from your getView() too

Comment: Glad to help, You can mark this answer as correct answer.. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

this is the adapter class code.

```
public class CustomTaskHistory extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Activity context;
    ArrayList<String> listTasks = new ArrayList<String>();

    String fetchRefID;
    StringBuilder responseOutput;
    ProgressDialog progress;
    String resultOutput;


    public String getFetchRefID() {
        return fetchRefID;
    }

    public void setFetchRefID(String fetchRefID) {
        this.fetchRefID = fetchRefID;
    }


    public CustomTaskHistory(Activity context, ArrayList<String> listTasks) {
        super(context, R.layout.content_main, listTasks);
        this.context = context;
        this.listTasks = listTasks;


    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_task_history, null, true);
        TextView textViewName = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.firstLayout);


        //System.out.println("client_id" + _clientID);
        //TextView textViewDesc = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewDesc);
        //ImageView image = (ImageView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        if (position % 2 != 0) {
            linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.sky_blue);


        } else {
            linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);

        }

        textViewName.setText(listTasks.get(position));


        return listViewItem;
        }
    }
```

and now in the parent class you must have already added a list view in your xml file so now display code for it is below:

```
CustomTaskHistory customList = new CustomTaskHistory(TaskHistory.this, task_history_name);

            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            listView.setAdapter(customList);
```

you can also perform any action on clicking cells of listview.If needed code for it is below add just below the above code:

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Intent nextScreen2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SubscribeProgrammes.class);
                nextScreen2.putExtra("CLIENT_ID", _clientID);
                nextScreen2.putExtra("REFERENCE_ID", reference_IDs.get(i));
                startActivity(nextScreen2);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Clicked " + task_list.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @Apoorv Malhotra.I am looking into your code.I am little confused.Can u suggest me what mistake i am doing in my code?!1!

Comment: what is the actual problem you are facing ?

Comment: my listview not displaying Apoorv